# Getting the names of the libraries in Bento using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm struggling to get going using Applescript and Bento. Initially I'd like to get the names of the libraries and I'm trying to using the following script:

```
tell application "Bento"
repeat with i from 1 to count of libraries
    tell library i
        try
            set theName to name of library i
            log theName
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
end tell
```

With a typical error message being:

```
    get name of library 1 of library 1
    --> error number -1728 from «class GLib» 1 of «class GLib» 1
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction to get going with Applescript and Bento.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my error in the use of Applescript:

```
tell application "Bento"
repeat with i from 1 to count of libraries
    set theName to name of library i
    log theName
end repeat
end tell
```